# React trigger function on underlaying div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to adjust my fixed header depending on the div that is under the header.
this is a example:

https://playcode.io/1711733

I want it so that when im scrolling up, or scrolling down, the header "knows" what div is underneath.

Im gone use this so i can make the website logo change colors depending the underlaying div color (using dark and light sections)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do it in a lot of different ways, [here's a simple one with no libs and basic CSS on github](https://github.com/XYIAN/basic-js-sandbox-stackoverflow/tree/master/src/components/dynamicHeader)

I gave the containers extra large heights so it's easier to visualize

[Component](https://github.com/XYIAN/basic-js-sandbox-stackoverflow/blob/master/src/components/dynamicHeader/DynamicHeader.jsx)

```
import "./_dHeader.css";

export const DynamicHeader = () => {
  const [headerStyle, setHeaderStyle] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "black",
    color: "white",
  });

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const header = document.getElementById("sticky-header");
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

    sections.forEach((section) => {
      const rect = section.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (
        rect.top <= header.offsetHeight &&
        rect.bottom >= header.offsetHeight
      ) {
        setHeaderStyle({
          backgroundColor: section.dataset.color,
          color: section.dataset.textColor,
        });
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const sections = [
    { color: "white", textColor: "black", content: "Section 1" },
    { color: "black", textColor: "white", content: "Section 2" },
    { color: "white", textColor: "black", content: "Section 3" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <header id="sticky-header" style={headerStyle}>
        Sticky Header
      </header>
      {sections.map((section, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="section"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: section.color,
            color: section.textColor,
            height: "100vh",
          }}
          data-color={section.color}
          data-text-color={section.textColor}
        >
          <h2>{section.content}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[CSS](https://github.com/XYIAN/basic-js-sandbox-stackoverflow/blob/master/src/components/dynamicHeader/_dHeader.css)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.section h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```